# How to make reusable button

Tags: javascript, button, refactoring, reset

I'm new to JavaScript and I want to create a button that, when clicked, will change the position of the object. But after clicking once, nothing else works. Below I have provided the code with the very essence of the problem, and my code where I want to apply it. Maybe someone will tell you how to make a restart button correctly, instead of constantly creating new divs.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    
        <style>
            button {
            position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button>Add new position</button>
    
        <script>
        
            const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                btn.style.top = '50px';
            });
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

MY PROJECT

```
const yes = document.getElementById('yes');
const no = document.getElementById('no');
const body = document.querySelector('.body');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const reset = document.querySelector('.panel__close')
const bodyMessage = document.querySelector('.body__message')

const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() *100) +1;




yes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    body.innerHTML = '';
    const paraLox = document.createElement('p');
    paraLox.textContent = 'Congratulation, Jaba Loshara Ebaniy!';
    paraLox.style.fontSize = '3rem';
    paraLox.style.textAlign = 'center';
    paraLox.style.fontWeight = '1000';
    paraLox.style.color = 'red';
    body.appendChild(paraLox);



    reset.addEventListener('click', () => { // reset button
        paraLox.parentNode.removeChild(paraLox);
    
    
        const bodyError = document.createElement('div');
        bodyError.setAttribute('class', 'body__error-image');
        bodyMessage.appendChild(bodyError);
    
        const bodyErrorImage = document.createElement('img');
        bodyErrorImage.setAttribute('src', 'error.png')
        bodyErrorImage.style.width = '50px';
        bodyErrorImage.style.height = '50px';
        bodyError.appendChild(bodyErrorImage);
    
        const bodyText = document.createElement('div');
        bodyText.setAttribute('class', 'body__text');
        bodyText.textContent = 'Jaba Lox?';
        bodyMessage.appendChild(bodyText);
    
        const bodyButtons = document.createElement('div');
        bodyButtons.setAttribute('class', 'body__buttons');
        bodyMessage.appendChild(bodyButtons);
    
        const bodyButton1 = document.createElement('div');
        bodyButton1.setAttribute('class', 'body__button');
        bodyButton1.setAttribute('id', 'yes');
        bodyButton1.textContent = 'Yes';
        bodyButtons.appendChild(bodyButton1);
    
        const bodyButton = document.createElement('div');
        bodyButton.setAttribute('class', 'body__button');
        bodyButton.setAttribute('id', 'no');
        bodyButton.textContent ='No';
        bodyButtons.appendChild(bodyButton);
    
        });


});


no.addEventListener('click', () => {
    no.style.position = 'relative';
    no.style.top = randomNum + 'px';
    no.style.bottom = randomNum + 'px';
    no.style.left = randomNum + 'px';
    no.style.right = randomNum + 'px';
});
```

Comment: In the current state, your code says: when you click button, move the button to `50px` from the top. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want the button to keep moving down with each click. In that case, the callback currently keeps setting the distance from the top to 50px. All you need to do is have the function add 50 to the current value.

```js
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    
        <style>
            button {
            position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button>Add new position</button>
    
        <script>
        
            const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                btn.style.top = ((parseInt(btn.style.top,10) || 0) + 50) + 'px';
            });
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Test it [here](https://jsbin.com/koxumomeka/1/edit?html,output)

Things to note:

- The value is saved as a string with a pixel suffix, i.e. `"50px"`, so we'll use `parseInt()` to convert it to an int we can add to.
- Before setting the style, AKA before the first click, its value is `""` not 0, which doesn't work with `parseInt()`, hence the OR `||` operator.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works. As far as I understand, first we convert the style value to a number so that it can be incremented. Then we use the || operator, if this is the first click, then our value has been added to zero, not an empty string. And we add this whole block to the 50 I want, and at the end of "px".

Comment: Only I don't understand why you have to put ")" in front of "50".

Comment: @Kyzlyk Im glad you noticed that because I wasn't sure if I should keep it or leave it or explain why I did it. The code works fine without it, but I put it there for general readibility. It implies that first we resolve the number, then we convert it to a string with `+ 'px'`. It doesn't look as nice with it there, but I feel like it makes for better coding. That's my opinion and I'd like to hear from anyone who agrees or has a different one.

Comment: @Kyzlyk and you understand it correctly. Just to expand on the `||` operator. If we try to parse a blank string i.e. `parseInt("", 10)` it returns `NaN`. `NaN` or 'Not a Number' is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) like `undefined` or `null`. When  we use OR or AND in brackets, they evaluate it different ways. `(a || b)`  returns the first truthy value. So if `a` is falsy, it returns `b`, if `a` is truthy it returns `a`. With AND `(a && b)` it returns the the falsy value if it's there, and if both are truthy, it returns the last one. Try them in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much again, you have helped me a lot in my general understanding of javascript!!

Comment: No problem! As a fellow learner, I wish us both good luck! :)